# Combine hibernate full text search and JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I recently got familiar with Hibernate search API. How can I have full text search on an entity and also filter the result by one specific field? For example:

```
final FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

final QueryBuilder qb = ftem.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Item.class).get();

final org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
        .keyword()
        .onFields(Item_.CONTENT)
        .matching(match)
        .createQuery();

/* also here I want to filter the results for all the Items in which category equals to 2 */

final FullTextQuery persistenceQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, Item.class);

final List<Item> result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have exactly same problem! Unfortunately I did not find anything useful yet. Please also share the answer if you find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For this case you can use Hibernate-search **Filters**. You also need to index that particuler field you need for filtering although you don't need it for query itself.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html/ch05.html#query-filter

I use it myself and it works quiet good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know if it's right to index for example userId field and apply filter on it!! Like it's possible I have 20,000,000 records, and 1,000,000 of them have same userId. Is it fast enough to create filter on userId?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is really a problem. If you use some simple analyzer for that field. If you wanted to filtr on that field in SQL DB you would probably also use some index for that field.